# Filter - combining two SELECT statements

Tags: sql, asp.net, ssms

So, I've got these two tables - Items with everything about them and a constraint bound to the SupplierId of the Supplier table. I'm using the VS's integrated SQL stuff and I've been trying to implement an asp:TextBox with which I would filter the results. The WHERE part would look like this:

```
        [Item].[app_id]         = convert(int, @QueryParam) OR
        [Item].[Item_name]      = @QueryParam OR
        [Item].[Price]          = convert(float, @QueryParam) OR
        [Supplier].SupplierName = @QueryParam;
```

But I'm not sure how to write the complete statement, as it says that SupplierName could both refer to either one from Supplier or one from Item.Supplier - I assume it gets one through the SupplierId constraint.

In the very theory, it would select `Item.Id, Item.app_id, Item.Item_name, Item.Price, Supplier.SupplierName`

So what do I write there?

Comment: What's the database engine? SQL Server?

Comment: @The Impaler, yep, SSMS.